# What is the vim equivalent of emacs' reftex?

Tags: vim, emacs, latex, vi

I write a lot in LaTeX and I only use vi/vim. Looking at other editors (emacs, specifically) I notice that vi lacks an easy way to insert references and citations, with me having to do them by hand (all the rest doesn't really bother me). In emacs, this feature exists and is called reftex mode (if i'm not mistaken).

The closest thing on vi that I thought would have this was `auctex.vim`, but reading its [keybindings](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cmlr/Latex/auctex-vim-keybindings) I can't find such a mode anywhere.

So, is there something similar for vi/vim that I am missing?

Cheers

Comment: Vim has tons of plugins like https://github.com/vim-scripts/Citation.vim  - and vim is more powerful than vi - so google for specific plugin or a class of plugins and install it

Comment: That plugin looks pretty nice. Can't install it though. I'll search for similar plugins.

Comment: Look at vundle - https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim  - once this is isntalled you just edit your ~/.vimrc to add more plugins and install them (see in vundle's readme how to install plugins)

Comment: @dmitryro I took your advice, installed `vundle`, but ended up installing `vim-latex`, which turned out to solve my problem. I should have installed that plugin way before, but I never found this citing/referencing scheme when I read about it so I assumed it didn't have it. Anyway, thanks for the tip.